# Convert a socketio socket id into a socket object

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have an object full of users:

```
{
  user1: {
    name: 'user',
    id: 'hdqijhdwi' //socket id
  } //etc
}
```

I want to get the socket object given the user's name and socket id. Is there any way to get the user's socket given their socket id.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this code is server-side because of the node.js tag.  If that's the case, then you can use the `socket.id` to do a number of things.

For example, if the connection is in the top level namespace, then you can send to a given user with the `socket.id` like this:

```
io.to(id).emit("someEvent", someData);
```

If it's in a different namespace, you can do the same thing with the namespace instead of `io`.

Note that the `io.to()` and `namespace.to()` are documented to send to all sockets in a `room`.  But, this works for the socket.id because every socket is uniquely entered into a room that has the name of its id so this is a clever way to send to a socket by id.

---

Or, if you just want the `socket` object, you can get that from the top level namespace socket hash object like this:

```
let socket = io.connected[id];
if (socket) {
    socket.emit(someEvent, someData);
}
```